# MVC Binding List of Objects in Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to dynamically build a table that needs to be bound to a ViewModel on form submission.

First item is the Action the form is submitting to.  Then the Parent ViewModel and then the child ViewModel.  Below those are two text fields representing the data I need bound.

When I submit the form all the other fields from the page are bound to their respective property but the complex object of ProgramViewModels is not.

What am I missing?

```
public ActionResult Add(AddEntityViewModel viewModel){
 Code that does something
}

 public class AddEntityViewModel
    {
    public IList<int> Counties { get; set; }
    public IList<ProgramViewModel> Programs { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Regions { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityName))
            return false;

        if (Counties == null || Counties.Count == 0)
            return false;

        if (Programs == null || Programs.Count == 0)
            return false;

        if (Regions == null || Regions.Count == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}

public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public int Id;
    public string SystemId;
}

<input type="hidden" id="Programs[0]__Id" name="Programs[0].Id" data-programid="3" value="3">
<input type="text" id="Programs[0]__SystemId" name="Programs[0].SystemId" style="width:100%" maxlength="50">
```

**Update**:

Changed the fields to properties after adiga's answer. But that too did not fix the issue.

```
public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to initialize the `Programs` list first? Shouldn't you initialize the list by doing `Programs = new List<ProgramViewModel>()` in your `AddEntityViewModel`? Also if you have to grab user's input dynamically from a form, I will just build the object from client side and use jQuery post (`$.ajax` or `$.post`) to submit the form with the custom object. MVC is smart enough to bind the custom object to the view model you define.

Comment: @DavidLiang Building the object via javascript is my next step if I can't get this to work in a timely manner.  I was just hoping to use the form submission.

Comment: Then show us how your form looks like. The way you wrote `Programs[0].Id` makes me think you're using `@Html.Helper` to bind each `ProgramViewModel` to the form inputs. But then you mentioned in the post that you're trying to dynamically build the table. That's what confused me. If you want to submit dynamic data, you can't use `@Html.Helper` to bind the input values. It's better to just craft out the JavaScript object yourself on client side that matchs the view model on the Controller action and just do a Post back to server, without using form submit.

Comment: I am a complete moron.  Found the issue.  I had a field called Programs and I missed it when I looked over the form for duplicates.  Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProgramViewModel` contains fields. Change them to properties.

```
public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SystemId { get; set; }
}
```

The `DefaultModelBinder` uses reflection and binds only the properties and not fields.

Comment: Good catch thank you.  Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.  I'll update my original post with the new ProgramViewModel.

Comment: @Tyddlywink, after amending that error do you still get null values or a different problem?

Comment: @Tyddlywink you're doing something else wrong. Do you get list property null?

Comment: @Tyddlywink btw I have updated the question to keep the original post and added an "update" to avoid invalidating the answer and comments

Comment: I get a list property count of 0.  So not null just count of 0.

Comment: @Tyddlywink that's not possible. With the information provided in the question, this should work. Are you sure the inputs are nested within the form? Are you creating multiple inputs with same name attribute?

Comment: @adiga I agree it should be binding.  I double checked and the input fields are indeed in the form tag.   Also, I double checked and I don't have two inputs with the same id or name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a List of a object, you should be performing a foreach instruction to get all of them:

```
<% foreach(var x in values) { %>
<div>hello <%= x.name %></div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: The issue is that the Programs property of the AddEntityViewModel is null after form submission.  I'm building the table in Javascript as the user enters data.